# Loop infinito dá páginausando window.ready ou window.onload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu estou tentando carregar uma página ao satisfazer uma condição e com o código que fiz carrega mas entra num loop eterno. Já pesquisei e tentei tudo que vi mas não consegui o resultado esperado. Se alguém puder me ajudar. Esse código está na mesma página que desejo traduzir.Agradeço desde já a atenção.

```
<script>
    $(window).ready(function(){
        if(pais === 'brazil'){
              document.location = 'minhaurl.com?language=portuguese';                      
        }    
        else{
              document.location = 'minhaurl.com?language=english';            
       }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Você entende porque está entrando no loop? Qual resultado espera?

Comment: Se este código está no index de `minhaurl.com`, então ao carregar a página, ele roda o script, que seta o location para minhaurl.com, que roda o script, que seta o location para minhaurl.com, que roda o script, que seta o location para minhaurl.com e por aí vai...

Comment: @MagicHat Eu espero que ele carregue uma vez.

Comment: @hkotsubo Então isso eu entendi mas como eu poderia resolver?

Comment: Isso está acontecendo porque você está usando uma url relativa, coloque `http://` ou `https://` antes do domínio. Depois disso talvez tenha mais o que debugar, porque não está claro de onde vem o valor de `pais`.

Comment: "*como eu poderia resolver?*" - Depende, de onde vem a variável `pais`? Como/quando deveria mostrar determinado idioma? É o usuário que escolhe, é alguma outra ação do sistema que define isso? Etc etc etc... Sem saber disso, qualquer solução será chute - como a resposta abaixo, por exemplo, pois não dá pra saber se a situação abaixo se aplica (se é para setar o `language` somente se não existir, ou se pode sobrescrever um já existente, etc). Poderia [edit] a pergunta esclarecendo esses pontos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que isso irá resolver. Só fiquei na dúvida de onde vem a variável `pais`. A minha solução não é a melhor possível, porém irá resolver. Pelo o que entendi ele acontece o loop pois não existe uma validação se já foi setada o `language` para a página e por isso na minha solução eu busco os parâmetros da URL e verifico se ele existe

```
<script>
function getUrlParams(param) {
    var aParams = new Object();
    window.location.search.replace(/[\?&]([^=&]*)(?:=([^&]*))?/gi, function (substr, param, value, offset, str) {
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            value = '';
        }
        aParams[param] = decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    });
    if (param) {
        return aParams[param];
    }
    return aParams;
}

$(window).ready(function(){
    //busca os paramêtros da URL. Se não existir o parâmetro ele vai retornar undefined
    var language = getUrlParams('language');
    
    //Verifica se já existe o parâmetro de país. Se já existir não faz sentido fazer o document.location
    if(typeof language === 'undefined'){
        if(pais === 'brazil'){
            document.location = 'minhaurl.com?language=portuguese';
        }
        else{
            document.location = 'minhaurl.com?language=english';
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: Em vez de regex, pode usar `URL.searchParams`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams (já compatível com a maioria dos browsers atuais)

Comment: "*Se já existir não faz sentido fazer o document.location*" - e se a página já estiver em um idioma e o usuário quiser mudar para outro? Claro que isso não foi dito na pergunta, e por isso eu pedi mais detalhes (pois só com o que tem ali, não dá para saber se é ou não para ser assim)

Comment: faz sentido @hkotsubo .. realmente faltam informações pra ter uma boa solução